# Holdout data for loaded model

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

In a separate program, I train my neural network. The X and Y shapes of this trained network are (37, 145662) and (37,), respectively. In this program, my holdout X and Y shapes are (14, 5952) and (14,), respectively. Originally when I was evaluating the trained model with the holdout set, I was getting an error along the lines of "model expected size 145662 but got 5952."

I have evaluated trained models with holdout data from other projects and was able to get those to work, but I'm not able to figure this one out. I'm currently getting this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input 
shape to have value 145662 but received input with shape [None, 5952]
```

And this error occurs here:

```
score = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
```

The code:

```
model = load_model('my_model')
model.summary()

def combinefilesonetemperature(temperature):
  spectrum_filestring="/content/drive/My Drive/Super_Official_C140_Interpolated_Data/Holdout_Data/
  TCSPC-" + str(temperature) + "C.csv"
  spectrum_y_vals = pd.read_csv(spectrum_filestring, header=None).values.T[2]

  TCSPC_filestring="/content/drive/MyDrive/Super_Official_C140_Interpolated_Data/Holdout_Data/ 
  spectra-" + str(temperature) + "C.csv"
  TCSPC_y_vals = pd.read_csv(TCSPC_filestring, header=None).values.T[2] 
  combinedlist = np.concatenate([spectrum_y_vals, TCSPC_y_vals])
  return combinedlist

temperaturelist = ["36.2", "38.7", "42.4", "48.7", "52.5", "58.6", "60.6", "36.2", "38.7", "42.4", 
"48.7", "52.5", "58.6", "60.6"]
temperaturelist = [float(item) for item in temperaturelist]

numtemps = np.asarray(temperaturelist).size
# print(numtemps) #14
X=np.empty((numtemps, 5952)) 
Y=np.empty(numtemps) 
for (i, temperature) in enumerate(temperaturelist): 
   X[i] = combinefilesonetemperature(temperature)
   Y[i] = temperature
score = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0) 
print("Holdout Set Results: " + str(score))
```

Has anyone ran into this problem before or know where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Your X input has to be of shape (nrow, 145662) since those are the specified parameters of your model's input layer. For the other models you trained, do they use the Sequential Model as well?

Comment: Yes, they were sequential, too. Should I be reshaping the X input somehow?

Comment: I would strongly suggest visualising your train and holdout datasets. Firstly the number of features are mismatched and they are erroneously high. It would also help if you show the architecture of your model.